# SQL UPDATE WHERE CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion, lucee

I know my SQL knowledge is weak. Unfortunately I found out I know less than I had perviously thought.

I wrote an `UPDATE` command to use in a simple HTML settings page using a form. (There is some browser side validation and also more server side validation of the form data before the data reaches the UPDATE SQL).

My goal is to updated 1 column in 2 rows. Nothing else. But I was wrong. It updated the two target rows with the values expected. The SQL also `NULL`ed the column of all values in all the other rows.

My question 1: What caused this in my SQL??
My question 2: Is there a better way of performing this update??

```
<cfquery datasource="OurDBLocation" name="changeValues">
    UPDATE sometable
    SET rowvalueB = CASE
    WHEN rowvalueA = 'A123' THEN #val(FORM.a123value)#
    WHEN rowvalueB = 'A456' THEN #val(FORM.a456value)#
    END
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE rowvalueA IN ('A123','A456')
</cfquery>
```

NOTE: This is an internal form accessible only to developers with VPN access to our code base. We use Lucee (aka ColdFusion) on the back end for those that do not understand the `#val(FORM.a123value)#`

Comment: *"The SQL also NULLed the column of all values in all the other rows."* The above would have only updated rows where the value of `rowvalueA` had a value of `'A123'` or `'A456'`, **no** others. Note, however, in your `CASE` you check `rowvalueA` first, and then `rowvalueB` second, so unless both `rowvalueA` *and* `rowvalueB` have a value of `'A456'` then any rows where `rowvalueA` have a value of `'A456'` would have been updated to be `NULL`, as there was no `ELSE` in your `CASE` expression. I "smell" a typographical error. `rowvalueA` <> `rowvalueB`.

Comment: You should always use `cfqueryparam` for user inputs like `#val(FORM.a123value)#`.

Comment: In your `UPDATE`, add a default condition: `CASE... WHEN .... THEN.... ELSE rowvalueB END`. That will prevent the value from being updated to `NULL`. But I believe it will also act like an `INSERTED` record in your `OUTPUT`, since the row was updated.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. The only possibility is that I ran the above statement once in testing and it did not include the `END` condition. Would excluding the `END` condition cause the rest of the DB records to be `NULL`ed?

Comment: @RRK. Thank you. As noted `(There is some browser side validation and also more server side validation of the form data before the data reaches the UPDATE SQL).` This company does not believe in `cfqueryparam`. IDK why, they just do not. Either way I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: 2020-10-07

Per latest comments, if you want to reduce the number of `UPDATE`s, especially when it's not changing the value but still resulting in a write, you could use a CTE to filter only the rows you need to update and then work with just those.

```
<cfquery datasource="OurDBLocation" name="changeValues">
; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rowvalueB
    FROM sometable
    WHERE rowvalueA = 'A123'
        OR ( rowvalueA = 'A456' AND rowvalueB = 'A456' )
)
UPDATE cte
SET rowvalueB =
        CASE
            WHEN rowvalueA = 'A123' THEN <cfqueryparam value="#val(FORM.a123value)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            ELSE <cfqueryparam value="#val(FORM.a456value)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        END
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
;
</cfquery>
```

CTE UPDATEs are pretty awesome, if they are available in your flavor of SQL (and by marking `tsql`, I'm guessing you're SQL Server). Test it to make sure it works for your case. I don't know why a `cfquery` wouldn't run a CTE UPDATE properly, but I'm not able to test it right now.

In explanation of what is happening:
`;WITH cte AS..` creates the named CTE data set. Also see https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/
`SELECT...` defines the data that makes up the CTE. Since you want to filter for `rowvalueA IN (A123,A456)` but then update different values, I simplified the `WHERE` statement. You'll only update with `FORM.a456` value when both `rowvalueB` AND `rowvalueA` = 'A456'. So the CTE filters out all rows where `rowvalueA=A456` but `rowvalueB` is something other than `A456`. Those would be the records that were getting reset to `NULL` originally.
Then you use a normal `UPDATE` statement to update the CTE, which will pipe up to the actual rows from the table. Since you're still using a conditional value in the update, we have to use the `CASE...WHEN...` but the rows have already been filtered and simplified. We only need to check if `rowvalueA=A123`.

Also note that when I mentioned validation on the client, I wasn't saying to not do it. I was simply pointing out that client-side validation is trivial to bypass, so shouldn't be relied on for any sort of validation that is intended for anything more than client display or ease of use.

========== ORIGINAL ANSWER =======================

If I correctly understand your intent, your query appears to be mostly correct. You are only updating `rowdataB` in your table. But you aren't giving a default value if your `WHEN` conditions aren't met, so `NULL` is assigned to it.

```
<cfquery datasource="OurDBLocation" name="changeValues">
    UPDATE sometable
    SET rowvalueB = 
        CASE
            WHEN rowvalueA = 'A123' THEN <cfqueryparam value="#val(FORM.a123value)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            WHEN rowvalueB = 'A456' THEN <cfqueryparam value="#val(FORM.a456value)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            ELSE rowvalueB
        END
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE rowvalueA IN ('A123','A456')
</cfquery>
```

This just reassigns the value of `rowvalueB` back to itself if none of your `WHEN` conditions in your `CASE` are met. Because of the `WHERE` clause, it will ignore any other row.

I *think* this might add the row to your `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` if `rowvalueA` is `'A456'`, since it will match in your `WHERE` clause but not in your `WHEN` clause. If that's not what you're after, you might want to change your `WHERE`.

Comment: NOTE: Client-side validation should never be relied upon for anything more than prettifying up your UI. Even when coming from dev users. Probably ESPECIALLY when coming from dev users, who likely have above average permissions. Before you insert data into your database, or consume it any other way, always validate it somewhere under YOUR control (ie somewhere inside the server). And as mentioned above, take advantage of `cfqueryparam`

Comment: Thank you. As noted in my question: ` (There is some browser side validation and also more server side validation of the form data before the data reaches the UPDATE SQL)`

As for your answer, it would seem that adding `ELSE rowvalueB` condition creates unneeded writing to the DB. Regardless I will take this into consideration in the future.

Comment: @davidhartman00 Very true. However, not including it is also causing extra writing because the value is rewritten to NULL without any condition. You could modify the `WHERE` statement to filter out the rows that are being reset to `NULL`, or even better, possibly use a CTE and then `UPDATE` the CTE. I'll update my answer to show what I'm talking about.